# How can I add custome column on NewForm.aspx on SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint

There is a custome column name "Tag" in my Discussion List.

How can I add a textbox to init "Tag" column when I new one.

As we know, NewForm.aspx only show Subjet, Body textbox as default.
But only show Body text when reply.

How can i custome NewForm.aspx to show Subject, Tag,Body textbox when I new one and only show Body textbox when reply.

Thanks

Comment: @kedk: I don't understand your question.  Please edit your question and provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via SharePoint API you can define where a field should be displayed:

```
SPField f = list.Fields.GetField("Tag");
f.ShowInShowInNewForm = true;
f.Update();
```

There are several properties to control where a field should be displyed. Check [SPField class members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield_members.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. Jason. It resolve my question.
By the way. I have another solution to fix it.
Would you please help me to check my solution have any issuce?

My solution is:
New a Column name "Tag" in Schema.xml, Deploy project, go to List Setting ->Click link of Discussion on Content Types  ->Click link of  Add from existing site or list columns  on Columns -> Add "Tag" from List Column.

After that, I can show Tag column when new item and hide Tag when reply item.

Thank